# How to calculate in KM2 the area of an attribute within randomly selected grid cells in R

Tags: vector, extract, overlay, raster, spatial

I have load the country boundary for Honduras into R and created within it a 2km x 2km grid.
I have then selected 13 random cells from within the grid.

I have then loaded in a vector layer (which is the WWF ecoregions boundaries) which covers the area of Honduras. Within this vector is an attribute called BiomeRealm which describes what type of biomes is present within in polygon of the vector layer (e.g. grasslands or forest).

I have made sure two layers have the same projection.

What I want to do is now extract the area (in KM2) of the attribute BiomeRealm within the 13 random selected cells within the grid I created. My ideal output with would say something like:

BiomeRealm: NT14 - Area - 5km2

```
        NT7 - Area -7km2
```

How can I do this?

My code so far is:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
```

load an admin boudary

```
shp <- getData(country = "HND", level = 0)
plot(shp)
```

#transform to a metric coordinate system
shp <- spTransform(shp, CRSobj = "+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
+ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
plot(shp)

create a grid within this polygon with specified cell size - what cell size is this?

```
cs <- c(3.28084, 3.28084)*2000   #cell size of 2km by 2km (1 ft = 3.28084 m)
grdpts <- makegrid(shp, cellsize = cs)
```

Then, we convert this grid (which basically is a matrix of center points) to a SpatialPoints object

```
spgrd <- SpatialPoints(grdpts, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(shp)))
```

This can then be converted into a SpatialPixels object. (Note: adding the subset [shp, ] only selects points within the original polygons)

```
spgrdWithin <- SpatialPixels(spgrd[shp,])
plot(spgrdWithin, add = T)
```

change to spatial grid

```
spgrdWithin <- as(spgrdWithin, "SpatialGrid")
```

now need to select 13 random grids # SAYS SAMPLE FROM GRID, 13 CELLS, RANDOM)

```
s <- spsample(spgrdWithin, 13, "random")
plot(s)
```

now read in the WWF data

```
HNDWWF <- readOGR('.','HONDURAS_WWF')
plot(HNDWWF)
```

transform HND WWF layer to same coordiantes as grid

```
HNDWWFTRANS <- spTransform(HNDWWF, CRSobj = "+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m 
+no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
plot(HNDWWFTRANS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. There may be a much better and more direct way to get at what you are really after. So you may want to clarify. But below is how you might select 13 random cells and intersect these with polygons.

If you are going to use UTM for Honduras, then you need to pick the right zone (16)

```
library(raster)
v <- getData(country = "HND", level = 0)
crs <- "+proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=WGS84 +units=m"   
v <- spTransform(v, CRSobj = crs)
```

Create a raster with the desired resolution

```
r <- raster(v, res=2000)
r <- init(r, "cell")
# set areas outside Honduras to NA
r <- mask(r, v)
```

Sample 13 cells

```
set.seed(1)
s <- sampleRandom(r, 13)
s
# [1] 44486 48219 55229 72480 41917 71715 77681 59055 57573 35633 42037 40820
#[13] 60238
```

Now see where these are in the "bioregions" (here using adm1)

```
bio <- getData(country = "HND", level = 1)
bio <- spTransform(bio, crs) 

xy <- xyFromCell(r, s)
extract(bio, xy)[, "NAME_1"]
# [1] "Yoro"              "Yoro"              "Copán"            
# [4] "Francisco Morazán" "Yoro"              "Francisco Morazán"
# [7] "Valle"             "Francisco Morazán" "Francisco Morazán"
#[10] "Colón"             "Gracias a Dios"    "Yoro"             
#[13] "Olancho"
```

As for the area, given that we have set the resolution to 2000 m, each cell is 4 km2.